# Selenium py - Process unexpectedly closed with status 255

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to run a python script in a docker container. The script contains selenium commands. I'm trying to use headless Firefox. When I run the script, I get this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/setup.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 179, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 359, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 255
```

The versions are as follows:

- python 3.10
- selenium 4.1.0
- firefox  91.5.1
- geckodriver 0.30.0

I install Firefox and geckodriver via the Dockerfile.

```dockerfile
#=================
# Install Firefox
#=================
RUN apt-get -qy --no-install-recommends install \
    $(apt-cache depends firefox | grep Depends | sed "s/.*ends:\ //" | tr '\n' ' ')
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN wget --no-check-certificate -O /tmp/firefox-esr.tar.bz2 'https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-esr-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US'
RUN tar -xjf /tmp/firefox-esr.tar.bz2 -C /opt/ && \
    ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox && \
    rm -f /tmp/firefox-esr.tar.bz2
    
#=================
# Install Geckodriver
#=================
RUN curl -fL -o /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz \
        https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf /tmp/geckodriver.tar.gz -C /tmp/ && \
    chmod +x /tmp/geckodriver && \
    mv /tmp/geckodriver /usr/bin/geckodriver
```

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: No, I changed the browser to chrome where the error does not appear anymore. Found a helpful dockerfile [here](https://github.com/dimmg/dockselpy/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the poor souls banging their heads on this, downgrade Firefox.
This is the DockerFile content I'm using that works for my selenium project:

```
       RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y tzdata ca-certificates bzip2 curl wget libc-dev libxt6 \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y `apt-cache depends firefox-esr | awk '/Depends:/{print$2}'` \
    && update-ca-certificates \
    # Cleanup unnecessary stuff
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove \
                  -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/*

# install geckodriver

    RUN wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.31.0/geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz && \
        tar -zxf geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/bin && \
        chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver && \
        rm geckodriver-v0.31.0-linux64.tar.gz

# install firefox

    RUN FIREFOX_SETUP=firefox-setup.tar.bz2 && \
        wget -O $FIREFOX_SETUP "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-95.0.1&os=linux64" && \
        tar xjf $FIREFOX_SETUP -C /opt/ && \
        ln -s /opt/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox && \
        rm $FIREFOX_SETUP
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wish I would have come across your answer sooner. What works for me on debian 11 32-bit is: 'geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux32.tar.gz' with 'firefox-96.0.1.tar.bz2' (linux). After I got it working with 95.0.1 I tried firefox 96.0.1 to 112.0.1 and none above version 96.0.1 worked.

Comment: Addition: The problems in Debian 11 32-bit do not occur in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64-bit. 'geckodriver-v0.33.0-linux64.tar.gz' works with 'firefox-112.0.1.tar.bz2' (linux64).